# Vertical alignment of two tables

Tags: html, css

I have two table, like this:

```css
#reference
{
 font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 margin: 0px 10px 0px 15px;
 text-align: left;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 color: navy;
}

#reference th
{
 padding: 8px;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: normal;
 background: yellow;
 border-top: 2px solid #000;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
 border-left: 1px solid #000;
 border-right: 1px solid #000;
 color: navy;
 text-align: center;
}

#reference td
{
 padding: 8px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
 border-top: 1px solid #000;
 border-left: 1px solid #000;
 border-right: 1px solid #000;
 color: #669;
}

#reference tbody tr:hover td
{
 background: pink;
 color: #339;
}

#copy
{
 font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 margin: 0px 10px 0px 15px;
 text-align: left;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 color: navy;
}

#copy th
{
 padding: 8px;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: normal;
 background: yellow;
 border-top: 2px solid #000;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
 border-left: 1px solid #000;
 border-right: 1px solid #000;
 color: navy;
 text-align: center;
}

#copy td
{
 padding: 8px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
 border-top: 1px solid #000;
 border-left: 1px solid #000;
 border-right: 1px solid #000;
 color: #669;
}

#copy tbody tr:hover td
{
 background: pink;
 color: #339;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Tables test</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  <table id="reference">
   <thead>
    <th style="width: 100px;">t1 - header 1</th>
    <th style="width: 200px;">t1 - header 2</th>
    <th style="width: 250px;">t1 - header 3</th>
   </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>t1 - value 1</td>
    <td>t1 - value 2</td>
    <td>t1 - value 3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>t1 - value 4</td>
    <td>t1 - value 5</td>
    <td>t1 - value 6</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>t1 - value 7</td>
    <td>t1 - value 8</td>
    <td>t1 - value 9</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>

  <table id="copy">
   <thead>
    <th style="width: 300px; height: 0;">t2 - header 1</th>
    <th style="width: 250px; height: 0;">t2 - header 2</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td style="width: 300px;">t2 - value 1</td>
     <td style="width: 250px;">t2 - value 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td style="width: 300px;">t2 - value 3</td>
     <td style="width: 250px;">t2 - value 4</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

I need "t2 - header 1" to have exact same width as "t1 - header 1" + "t1 - header 2". I run several searches on the Internet, found same solutions, but all works for columns having same width, while i need to have predefined column widths. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need to have two distinct tables or can they be combined? Also, that's not valid HTML5.

Comment: Two distinct tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use percentages?

If you're sticking to 550px just set it in the code and use percentages of 550px or whatever table you use in the future to keep it the same.

You can look into bootstrap tables to get an advanced look at table manipulation (condensed tables, responsive tables, etc.)

```css
table {
  width:550px;
 }

#reference
{
 font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 margin: 0px 10px 0px 15px;
 text-align: left;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 color: navy;
}

#reference th
{
 padding: 8px;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: normal;
 background: yellow;
 border-top: 2px solid #000;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
 border-left: 1px solid #000;
 border-right: 1px solid #000;
 color: navy;
 text-align: center;
}

#reference td
{
 padding: 8px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
 border-top: 1px solid #000;
 border-left: 1px solid #000;
 border-right: 1px solid #000;
 color: #669;
}

#reference tbody tr:hover td
{
 background: pink;
 color: #339;
}

#copy
{
 font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 margin: 0px 10px 0px 15px;
 text-align: left;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 color: navy;
}

#copy th
{
 padding: 8px;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: normal;
 background: yellow;
 border-top: 2px solid #000;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
 border-left: 1px solid #000;
 border-right: 1px solid #000;
 color: navy;
 text-align: center;
}

#copy td
{
 padding: 8px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
 border-top: 1px solid #000;
 border-left: 1px solid #000;
 border-right: 1px solid #000;
 color: #669;
}

#copy tbody tr:hover td
{
 background: pink;
 color: #339;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Tables test</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  <table id="reference">
   <thead>
    <th style="width: 20%;">t1 - header 1</th>
    <th style="width: 35%;">t1 - header 2</th>
    <th style="width: 45%;">t1 - header 3</th>
   </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>t1 - value 1</td>
    <td>t1 - value 2</td>
    <td>t1 - value 3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>t1 - value 4</td>
    <td>t1 - value 5</td>
    <td>t1 - value 6</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>t1 - value 7</td>
    <td>t1 - value 8</td>
    <td>t1 - value 9</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>

  <table id="copy">
   <thead>
    <th style="width: 55%;">t2 - header 1</th>
    <th style="width: 45%;">t2 - header 2</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>t2 - value 1</td>
     <td>t2 - value 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>t2 - value 3</td>
     <td>t2 - value 4</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is modify the width of "t2 - header 1"

```
<th style="width: 317px; height: 0;">t2 - header 1</th>
```

Comment: From where did you get 317? What is the logic behind this? What to do if i need another layout, start trying different widths, from pixel to pixel, until tables fits? I was asking for a general solution.